# Div tag disappears after the animation finishes on ipad when using jquery slideDown 

Tags: jquery, css, ipad, animation, slidedown

I am using `$('div#MainNavigation').slideDown('medium');` to slide down a div tag. On completion of the animation on the iPad, it disappears.

The site i'm using this on is www.missbossyboots.com.au Clicking the logo in the top left activates the sliding code.

Comment: while fixing another issue, i added some padding to the bottom of the div#MainNavigation  This has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

For me, contrary to Gavin Bruce, it was because of the padding bottom that my div disappeared!

To fixed it, I simply add a the css "**overflow: hidden;**" to the slideUp/slideDown element (A div in my case).

Comment: Thanks for this. This solution also works for me. I have a <ul> sliding Up/Down and one element is an arrow (&#x25BC;) in a <span> tag. Was disappearing after slideDown completed on iOS browsers.

Comment: Worked for me as well on a the <section> element I was trying to slide Up/Down, thanks a lot!

Comment: Worked for me ! Thanks a lot!!
My datatable child row disappeared on ios after sliding it down. overflow:hidden on the "slide down div" fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but I found this question while I was experiencing this very problem, and Gavin's comment did NOT resolve my issue (nor would it have looked correct with the given design).

While I was banging my head against the wall as this worked properly in every browser out there **except**  IOS Safari, I finally discovered the culprit in MY case:

a misplaced `z-index` tag.

Here's the "light" version of my code:

```
<div class="children"> <!-- this is the container, which is the target of a jQuery slideDown() -->
    <ul> <!-- this element would "pop" outside of the container after animation completed -->
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a><li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Originally, I had `z-index: 3000;` applied to the `<ul>` element.

After I removed it from the ul and moved it to the `<div class="children">` element, my problems went away, and the ul stayed where it belonged after the animation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same (or similar) problem - content is "jumping outside" of it's container after the jquery slideDown() transition. For me, it has nothing to do with z-index. I solved it by removing the style "position:relative;" (making it "static") for the element that is jumping. I'm still unclear to me as to why this is happening, and removing position:relative is not always an option. I'm using jquery 1.9.1, and I'm not sure if this is a bug in jquery.